# UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name -

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I am trying to rename columns after I read in a csv file where I want to replace a portion of the column name.
Here is my code where I want to remove :

```
'yor_yogurt_march_poggen_output_with_shrink.'
```

I get a user warning. I am using the **pandas library** if that matters.

```
df.dolumns =  df.columns.str.replace('yor_yogurt_march_poggen_output_with_shrink.', '')
```

Comment: Glad you asked it lol, had same problem with same typo :P

Comment: Well, I made a similar typo: df.colums and got the same warning :P

Comment: @XinNiu I also made that typo, and found this question highly useful because of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check `df.dolumns` is a typo in your post, but hopefully not in your code? Because it thinks you're trying to set a new attribute `.dolumns` for your df

Comment: After lurking on Stack overflow for the longest time I ask a question but it turns out it was typo on my end.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Better to ask than not ask, even if the answer is simple!

Comment: This just tripped me up as well. Embarrassing! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is in the title of your question: **Pandas doesn't allow columns
to be created via a new attribute name**.

If your *df* does not have a column with the given name,
you can not refer to this name using attribute notation
(in this case *df.dolumns*).

You have to specify the new column name as an index, i.e.:

```
df['dolumns'] = ...
```

Another detail: After `=` you have `df.columns` which is a **list** of
column names existing so far.
As I understood, you want to perform the same replace in each column name (deleting the mentioned fragment).
So maybe the resulting list of column names should be substituted
under **df.columns** (statring with **c** not **d**)?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You were right, I needed to use df.columns not df.dolumns.  Type mistake.